# Basic Import from Submodule Fails in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, ide, spyder, importerror

I know this *should* work. But it doesn't. What could be the reason?

Using python 3.9, Anaconda environment, Spyder 5.4.3, Windows 10

```
├── sub
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── util.py
|
├── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

```
# util.py
def my_func():
    print("test")
```

```
# main.py
from sub.util import my_func

>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason myself. This can easily happen when you're working on scripts in several directories in parallel and execute only *parts of it* like a single line or cell of code (<kbd>Strg+Enter</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd>)

In this case Spyder doesn't change the *current working directory* (checked via `os.getcwd()` ) which can cause confusion.

Using <kbd>F5</kbd> (run file) always implicitly changes the cwd to the file's directory and the imports work.